# bash search line matching hash and output it to a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have this very large text file 3GB and I need to process only those lines having a MD5 hash. I expect the file to be much shorter after taking out only those lines having an MD5. What I was thinking was doing something like this:

```
$cat myfile.txt | grep '[a-fA-F0-9]{32}' > only_lines_with_hashes.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: Using cat to pipe the file to grep is a bit redundant.

Comment: Looks fine, what's the problem?

Comment: @jkshah happened that there is no output

Comment: I think you need to add -E, for extended regexp patterns. like 
grep -E '[a-fA-F0-9]{32}'

Comment: Also, in order to avoid including non-md5 long strings that match (e.g.  a string of 100 characters of `[a-fA-f0-9]`), you can use the `-w` flag of grep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` uses BREs by default. Those generally don't include `{n}`, but I believe Gnu grep will accept an escaped version, try

```
grep '[[:xdigit:]]\{32\}' myfile.txt > hashes.txt
```

Or tell it the RE is extended, with `-E`

```
grep -E '[[:xdigit:]]{32}' myfile.txt > hashes.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping `{}` with `\`. and use of `cat` is redundant.

```
grep '[a-fA-F0-9]\{32\}' myfile.txt > only_lines_with_hashes.txt
```